# Can't see debug info Xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I think I've accidentally removed some kind of setting or something on a project level. In project A I can see debug info, but in project B I can't see a damn thing while debugging. Local variables can't be expanded to see what they contain, and neither variabels located in `self`.

As stated earlier, it works fine in one project, but not at all in another. I have no idea what I've done, or how to solve it. I asked around with a few coworkers and none has experienced this before. Kind of need to fix this in order to work efficiently.

Here is a screenshot displaying what I mean:
[image]

I don't have any variables in self here, but if I add some or store some, it doesn't work anyway. I can't see anything in `self` since I can't expand it at all.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Anyone? I've checked the schemes and it's set to debug, and I can see some local variables but nothing in self. This is making it impossible for me to debug. I have also tried creating an entirely new project and it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Or rather I found the issue. The issue seems to be with either Xcode 6.4 and above, or GoogleMaps in general. When importing GoogleMaps SDK the debugger stops working properly. Simple as that. Comment out your import of GoogleMaps SDK and the debugger will be back to normal.

Another way of solving this is to bridge GoogleMaps SDK from ObjC to Swift rather than importing it in Swift. I didn't try this, but I saw this as a possible solution here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8524

Hope it helps someone. Took me days to find this information.